# embedding Equinox in a Servlet Container

Tags: osgi, tomcat7, equinox

I m trying to embed Equinox in a Servlet Container,being a newbie,
I am trying to deploy bridge.war from http://www.eclipse.org/equinox/server/http_in_container.php in tomcat 7 on linux.
catalina.out doesnt show any errors but if i try to access anything from tomcat, even the tomcat index page, it keeps trying to simply connect and does not turn up anything.

When I try to stop Tomcat server, i get the following errors :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:337)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:198)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:452)
```

Has someone got this problem ? How can I get it working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it looks like you Tomcat has a big problem, totally regardless of Equinox.

To confirm that, remove bridge.war and its expanded folder, and restart TC, I think you'll see the same problem.

My guess is that there is already some process using (one of) the ports TC wants to use, and Tomcat can not start properly, you should see something going wrong in catalina.out OR the localhost.* log file.

Comment: Before deploying bridge.war , tomcat runs fine , but if I deploy bridge.war, start , then stop tomcat and try to restart it , then it shows that the port is being used.

Comment: Weird.Maybe you've added a bundle that starts its own webserver from within the war file, like org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty?

Comment: Or tomcat simply does not shut down at all?

Comment: Thnks for pointing out,one of the wtbwebapps sets up a netty server on a different port,will remove it and try.Skipped my mind to look into that.

Comment: I cleaned and removed all other webapps from tomcat and am only deploying bridge.war then also getting the same issue :(

Comment: Then it *must* be something happening within the bridge.war. Is that the standard equinox bridge.war you can download?